# Inconsistent datetime object in Python3 and Django2

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, django-models

Python 3, Django 2

I am trying to get a function to consistently return a datetime object.

Here are the conditions where it does and does not work.

I have a function that generates a datetime object with an offset like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime
def off_time():
    date = datetime.now()
    offset = settings.TIME_OFFSET
    offtime = date + offset
    return offtime
```

TIME_OFFSET is generated in settings thus:

```
from datetime import timedelta
TIME_OFFSET = timedelta(days=370000)
```

If I save to a model object like this:

```
from django.db import models
import stellar.physics_tools
class Test(models.Model):
    cdate = models.DateTimeField(default=stellar.physics_tools.off_time, help_text='When Generated')
```

and then work on the cdate, I can do this:

```
cdate = test.cdate
creation_date = cdate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and it works ok.

but if I try this:

```
    newtime = stellar.physics_tools.off_time
    return newtime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I get:
'function' object has no attribute 'strftime'

I need this function to return an object that I can use .strftime on, at least.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work I need to call the function with () like this:

```
newtime = stellar.physics_tools.off_time()
```

I was not doing this because if I did this in the Django model construction it returns the value created when the class is defined, which is not what I want.

In short I still need to use stellar.physics_tools.off_time in the Django model, but when calling the function outside of this I need to use stellar.physics_tools.off_time().